# C# - Selenium Opera Driver Crash

Tags: c#, selenium

Am trying to use Selenium on Opera browser 
here is my code :

```
 IWebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://Google.com");
```

I have downloaded Selenium Opera driver to my desktop version 0.2.2

and I have downloaded Selenium via Nuget version 3.0.1

Am getting this error

> > An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in listboxtest.exe Additional information: A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52804/session. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

what wrong am doing ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable port 52804 and OperaDriver exceptions in your firewall (Windows Firewall, probably)